# Unexpected 'OrElse' behavior in Linq query

Tags: vb.net, linq, .net-4.0, ado.net

I'm having problems with the following Linq query (demandNb is a filter option, as a string):

```
Return (From auto In entity.DEMDT_AUTMT _
    Where (String.IsNullOrEmpty(demandNb) OrElse auto.DEMND_NB = demandNb) _
    Order By auto.NO_DEMND Descending _
    Select auto).ToList()
```

My goal is to get all demands for the database if the filter fields is empty. If there is a filter, the function should return all demands that match the filter.

Currently, when I try to convert the IQueryable collection to a list using .ToList(), the following error is thrown:

```
Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.
```

The problem is, when demandNb is equal to "", this instruction `auto.DEMND_NB = demandNb` is still executed, throwing a conversion error.

When I remove the part after OrElse, everything works fine (although this is not the behavior I want, I want the filter to work afterall!). I have also tried to put the result in a variable (which works), and then convert it to a list, and the error is only thrown when .ToList() is called. Wierd...

Is there something I am not seeing, and why is not `OrElse` working as intended?

**Edit:**

I will be implementing several more filter fields like this (like demand owner, demand date, etc), so I cannot verify the if the filter is empty before executing the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say `auto.DEMND_NB` is of type `Double`, and `demandNb` is obviously a `string`. This has nothing to do with the `OrElse`: you're just trying to compare two values of non-compatible types.

Since the value of `demandNb` is not tied to each row in the data, I'd suggest doing something like this (pardon the C#):

```
var autos = entity.DEMDT_AUTMT;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(demandNb))
{
    var demandNbDouble = double.Parse(demandNb);
    autos = autos.Where(auto => auto.DEMND_NB == demandNbDouble);
}
autos = autos.OrderBy(...);
```

Comment: DEMND_NB is an integer (That missing CInt is so obvious I didn't see it). Although, when demandNb is empty or null, the other part of the expression shouldn't be evaluated at all, but it is, which is puzzling me.

Comment: @Msonic: You're talking about *compile-time* evaluation of your code, which is always going to be aware of the declared types of your variables, so even if the *runtime* execution never gets to that point, you'll still get a compiler error.